# How to do grep so the results are shown with surroundings

Tags: bash, grep, find

I'm not even sure if this is possible using grep or if any other tools is needed. I'll explain what I want to do.

If I have a file foo.txt like the following:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

When doing `grep c foo.txt` I want the result to be something like this:

```
b
c
d
```

Being the result and its surroundings.

Is this possible? Which is the option to be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-C` (context) flag of grep. Similar flags are `-A` (after) and `-B` (before). The argument is the number of lines in the context.

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -1 c foo.txt
```

`-1` means one line before and after

Answer (score 1):

additional to `-C` you can use the directional options `-B <number>`  and `-A <number>` to specify the number of lines before and after the match.